# Jump anywhere with in text with Vim

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin, viemu

I'm an beginner vim user and I installed `VimFx` add-on for Firefox in order to get used easier with it. And `VimFx` has this cool feature where when you press `F` you get a bunch of links where you can jump. And when you press the link's shortcut you get to that page. I want the same thing in Vim but to jump at that particular piece of text. I remember I say the same thing in `Vim` but I don't remember if there was a plug-in or if it was built-in. Like here:

[image]

Is that feature available for `ViEmu` for `Visual Studio`? And if yes, how can I enable it?
Also is it possible to use `Vim` plug-ins with `ViEmu`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is inspired by a Vim plugin called [EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion).

As far as I know, there isn't a single vi[m] emulator out there that supports Vim plugins. Some emulators, like Vrapper for Eclipse provide their own implementation of famous plugins but that's how far you can go.

But if you want a definitive answer, read [the ViEmu documentation](http://www.viemu.com/viemu_doc.html).

---

Using a vi[m] emulator is a very poor way to learn Vim. Use Vim itself.

Installing plugins is also a very poor way to learn Vim. Learn the basics first.

Comment: It's impossible to use `Vim` with a complex Visual Studio project where you really need autocompletion and the debugger, but yes, the answer is good...

Comment: Who said you should learn Vim in a production environment? That would be crazy. Learn Vim on the side and switch if/when you are ready. Also, Vim is not an IDE: don't waste your time learning it if you have no real need for a *text editor*.

Comment: The problem is not with learning Vim. The problem is that for big VS projects it's impossible to use Vim no matter how guru you are with Vim. You can't use the VS debugger from within Vim and the autocompletion features won't work because AFAIK there is no autocompletion plugin out there that would understand project files

Comment: This is not a problem. If you need an IDE, use an IDE; if an IDE is not strictly necessary, you can use Vim. If all you do is C# and you absolutely need VS, there is simply no point learning Vim at all. I use Vim for HTML/CSS/JS, Python, shell scripting, lightweight PHP and any other text editing task on one side and Flash Builder for AS3 and AndroidStudio pour Android on the other side. If I was doing only Android dev or AS3 or C# I would never have bothered to learn Vim as it would have been useless/worthless to me.

Comment: But you started your question with "I'm an beginner vim user" and yeah, trust me on that: using vim emulators and installing fancy plugins are not good ways to learn Vim. If you are serious about learning Vim, that is. I "expanded" my answer because of the VS angle of your question: since Vim doesn't seem to be useful in your workflow, I raised a possible issue regarding your actual need to use/learn Vim at all.

Comment: I'm using Vim for my personal projects and while using VS I always find myself in those situations where you need 2 keystrokes to do something which in VS needs 6 and it's annoying. That's why I am searching for these things...Just using the arrows and the mouse all the time pisses me off

Comment: And I can very well understand that. That's why ViEmu, Vrapper and friends exist. But they are not Vim and they have *many* missing parts. Using Vrapper in Flash Builder, I always have "oh, shit" moments where something I'm used to in Vim is not available despite all the basic text-objects and motions being present. I'm afraid there's no perfect solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, the `f`,`F` (and associated `t`, `T`) motions do exist by default on Vim (and most emulators), but there are limited to the same line.

See `:help left-right-motions`

As mentioned before, EasyMotion allow you to do a search on multiple lines.